# Android TTS initializing slowly

Tags: text-to-speech

We are developing an update to [French English Dictionary + for Android](http://www.vidalingua.com/french-english-dictionary-android.php) and TTS is giving us grief. The first time a user taps a speaker to hear pronunciation, it's taking upwards of 14 seconds to initialize TTS and deliver a result. This only happens for the secondary language (not the device's default language).

We have tried writing a 2 line code snippet to test in isolation, same result. We also tried initializing TTS on startup and pronouncing a blank string but still no luck.

Comment: Add some code then. We can't guess what your code looks like at all.

Comment: You can find code at https://gist.github.com/savytskyi/39d96aaaf009df3568455ef7566a2021